# How to ignore all files of a folder or only folders in tailwindcss?

Tags: node.js, tailwind-css

I am using tailwindcss. In `tailwind.config.js` file, I found a `content` option. When I used `./**/*.{html,js}` in this option, It also search for `node_modules` directory. But I want to ignore that directory. Now what to do?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `**/something` is called glob pattern, a way to match multiple paths at once.
`**` matches every subfolder, so if you want to exclude something I'd recommend include everything inside the `src` folder, instead of trying to exclude some other folder, like so:

```
./src/**/*.{html,js}
```

More on glob patterns [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-using-globs-node-js/)